# Compute Integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\left ( \int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|} dy\right ) dx$

Tags: integration, analysis, lebesgue-integral, fubini-tonelli-theorems

could you help me understand how to obtain the repeated integral.
Should I use Fubini?
I thank you for any hint or solution.

> Problem: Let $f(x,y)=\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|}$

Is the Lebesgue double integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y) dx dy$ equal to the repeated Lebesgue integral $\int_{0}^{\infty}(\int_{0}^{\infty}f(x,y) dy)dx$?

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|} dx dy=\int_{0}^{\infty}\left (  \int_{0}^{\infty}\operatorname{sgn}(x-y)e^{-|x-y|} dy\right ) dx$$

Comment: Replace the inner integral with respect to y with the integral from 0 to x plus the integral from x to infinity.

Comment: You really could replace the sgn part with $\pm$ and a restriction based on sgn as sgn only can equal 0,-1,1 or only 1,-1 based on convention. You can do something similar for -|x-y| and add restrictions.